# How to make elements size fixed (Arcobjects)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm using arcobjects .Net 10 to add graphic elements to my map.
My problem is that when the map scale changes, the element size change too.
How to fix element size at all scales?

Answer (score 3):

Try having a look at the ITextElement interface. You can set the ScaleText property to False so it will not change scales as the map extent changes.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITextElement_Interface/001200000r70000000/

EDIT:  Sorry, just saw you are using graphic elements.  The IElementProperties3 interface has a ReferenceScale property.  You can set that to the current scale when the graphic is drawn:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ReferenceScale_Property/001200000469000000/

Comment: Thank you @crmackey for reply, but it didn't work. I want to make a "fixed screen size" effect just like ArcMap do.